# SQL Server: Turning rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to make the following structure

```
ROW | GROUP | ORDER | COL_NAME  | VALUE
---------------------------------------------
1   | 10    | 10    | FIRST_COL | Value1
2   | 10    | 10    | FIRST_COL | Value2
3   | 10    | 10    | FIRST_COL | Value3
4   | 10    | 20    | SECOND_COL| Val1
5   | 10    | 20    | SECOND_COL| Val2
6   | 20    | 10    | THIRD_COL | Opt3
...
```

into

```
FIRST_COL   | SECOND_COL    | THIRD_COL
-----------------------------------------------------
Value1      | Val1          | Opt3
Value2      | Val2          |
Value3      |               |
```

What I currently have:

```
declare @cols varchar(max),
        @query varchar(max)
select @cols = stuff((select ',' + quotename([COL_NAME])
                    from mt
                    group by [COL_NAME]
                    for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');


set @query = 'select ' + @cols + ' from (
    select [COL_NAME], [VALUE]
    from mt
) x
pivot (
    min([VALUE])
    for [COL_NAME] in (' + @cols + ')
) p
';
execute(@query);
```

The current code only shows the minimum values (since it's set to `min([VALUES])`), so only Value1, Val1 and Opt3 would be shown, but my question here is, how can I modify the code so I get the appropriate table/view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need this:

```
set @query = 'select ' + @cols + ' from (
    select [COL_NAME], [VALUE], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [COL_NAME] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
    from mt
) x
pivot (
    min([VALUE])
    for [COL_NAME] in (' + @cols + ')
) p
';
```

The `pivot` uses all the columns in the subquery.  You just need one to distinguish among the rows with the same column name.

Comment: Great, this is the easiest approach (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
Declare @YourTable table ([ROW] int,[GROUP] int,[ORDER] int,[COL_NAME] varchar(50),[VALUE] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
(1,10,10,'FIRST_COL' ,'Value1'),
(2,10,10,'FIRST_COL' ,'Value2'),
(3,10,10,'FIRST_COL' ,'Value3'),
(4,10,20,'SECOND_COL','Val1'),
(5,10,20,'SECOND_COL','Val2'),
(6,20,10,'THIRD_COL' ,'Opt3')


;with cteBase as (
    Select *
          ,RowNr = Row_Number() over (Partition By [COL_NAME] Order by [ROW])
     From @YourTable
)
Select First_Col  = max(case when [COL_NAME]='FIRST_COL'  then Value else '' end)
      ,Second_Col = max(case when [COL_NAME]='SECOND_COL' then Value else '' end)
      ,Third_Col = max(case when [COL_NAME]='THIRD_COL' then Value else '' end)
 From  cteBase
 Group By RowNr
```

Returns

```
First_Col   Second_Col  Third_Col
Value1      Val1        Opt3
Value2      Val2    
Value3
```

Comment: You've beaten me by seconds... +1 for the speed :-) But Gordons answer is better than both of us, I'm afraid...

Comment: @Shnugo you're right, but I really appreciate both of your andwers, they still could be of use for different scenarios!

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([ROW] INT,[GROUP] INT,[ORDER] INT,[COL_NAME] VARCHAR(100),VALUE VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,10,10,'FIRST_COL','Value1')
,(2,10,10,'FIRST_COL','Value2')
,(3,10,10,'FIRST_COL','Value3')
,(4,10,20,'SECOND_COL','Val1')
,(5,10,20,'SECOND_COL','Val2')
,(6,20,10,'THIRD_COL','Opt3');

WITH Sorted AS
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.[COL_NAME] ORDER BY tbl.[ROW]) AS SortInx
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Sorted.[COL_NAME]='FIRST_COL' THEN Sorted.[VALUE] END) AS FIRST_COL 
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Sorted.[COL_NAME]='SECOND_COL' THEN Sorted.[VALUE] END) AS SECOND_COL 
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Sorted.[COL_NAME]='THIRD_COL' THEN Sorted.[VALUE] END) AS THIRD_COL 
FROM Sorted
GROUP BY SortInx
```

Answer (score 0):

As he stated, you need to use RowNumber() to populate your Row column, on your COL_NAME, so your data will look like this.

```
ROW | GROUP | ORDER | COL_NAME  | VALUE
---------------------------------------------
1   | 10    | 10    | FIRST_COL | Value1
2   | 10    | 10    | FIRST_COL | Value2
3   | 10    | 10    | FIRST_COL | Value3
1   | 10    | 20    | SECOND_COL| Val1
2   | 10    | 20    | SECOND_COL| Val2
1   | 20    | 10    | THIRD_COL | Opt3
...
```

Then, just include the column in your SQL

```
set @query = 'select [Row], ' + @cols + ' from (
    select [Row],[COL_NAME], [VALUE]
    from mt
) x
pivot (
    min([VALUE])
    for [COL_NAME] in (' + @cols + ')
) p
';
execute(@query);
```

Then, you have

```
ROW FIRST_COL   SECOND_COL  THIRD_COL
1   Value1          Val1            Opt3
2   Value2          Val2            NULL
3   Value3          NULL            NULL
```

Comment: Don't you think the `ROW` column has unique numbers for any reason? Gordons solution does exactly the same (but creating a new column)... The main puzzle was to *achieve* this grouped and sorted list of numbers...